# How can I convert a range to a string (VBA)?

Tags: vba, macos, excel, excel-2011

What is the best way to convert a range of cells to a string?
I have a function that only takes a string as input so I need to convert the range to a string, while retaining as much of the formatting as possible (i.e. it needs to look like a table or list, not just a string of characters).
I've tried working with CStr(), as well as converting from a range to an array and then to a string, but I just get errors.

Edit: Code attempt

```
Dim email_answer As Integer
email_answer = MsgBox("Do you want to be emailled a copy of this schedule?", vbYesNo)
If email_answer = vbYes Then

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim to_send As Range
    to_send = Range("D3", "D10")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 14 Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        MailFromMacWithMail body content:=CStr(to_send), _
                    mailsubject:="Schedule", _
                    toaddress:="email address", _
                    ccaddress:="", _
                    bccaddress:="", _
                    attachment:=.FullName, _
                    displaymail:=False
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: share your code attmept

Comment: How do you expect a string to look like a table?

Comment: Sorry @ShaiRado Code attempt added now (this was the last attempt, have also tried range->array->string method).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make a comma separated list of cell values in a range:

```
Function RangeToString(ByVal myRange as Range) as String
    RangeToString = ""
    If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim myCell as Range
        For Each myCell in myRange
            RangeToString = RangeToString & "," & myCell.Value
        Next myCell
        'Remove extra comma
        RangeToString = Right(RangeToString, Len(RangeToString) - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

You could add extra functionality like inserting a semicolon instead of a comma if the row number increases.

To use this function:

```
Sub AnySubNameHere()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A10")

    Dim myString as String
    myString = RangeToString(rng)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the novice question. I added your code and then called it using

`Dim to_send As Range`
`to_send = Range("D3", "D10")`
`Call RangeToString(to_send)`

Will this change to_send to a string?
My code still returned a byref argument mismatch error when I did this

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how to use this function. The function returns a string object, so you can just assign that to a variable :)

Comment: you are amazing, thank you so much! Is there a way to make it run down each column before moving to the next row? At the moment it appears to be reading A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2 etc. instead of A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3 etc.

Comment: You could loop through the columns `For Each rowRange in myRange.Rows` then loop through cells in each `rowRange` instead of in the whole of `myRange`. Note you should `Dim` the Range object `myRow` first

Comment: Thanks, but now it's given me a runtime error 13 type mismatch. Did I implement your solution correctly?

`Dim myCell As Range
        Dim RowRange As Range
        For Each RowRange In myRange.Rows
        
            For Each myCell In RowRange

                RangeToString = RangeToString & Chr(13) & myCell.Value

            Next myCell
        Next RowRange`

Comment: You can change the "," into chr(13) so you can have it displayed with newline

Answer (score 7):

you could use this function:

```
Function Rang2String(rng As Range) As String
    Dim strng As String
    Dim myRow As Range
    With rng
        For Each myRow In .Rows
            strng = strng & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myRow.value)), "|") & vbLf
        Next
    End With
    Rang2String = Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1)
End Function
```

which would return a string with linefeed character as range rows separator and pipes ("|") as columns separator

Comment: Good use of Transpose twice to convert 2d array to 1d array (something I've only just learnt from SO)!

Comment: @SMeaden, it's needed for "rows" ranges while for "columns" ones you only need one transpose

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is already almost a year old, but I found a quick solution that works for me:
You do have to create a reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library to use the DataObject.

```
Public Function GetStringFromRange(RNG As Range) As String
    Dim DOB As New MSForms.DataObject
    RNG.Copy
    DOB.GetFromClipboard
    GetStringFromRange = DOB.GetText
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to iterate.

```
Application.Textjoin(Chr(10),TRUE,Range("D3", "D10"))
```

or

```
Join(Application.Transpose(Range("D3:D10")),Chr(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way.
Assuming the variable rng is a range, then writing:

rng = Left(rng,Len(rng))

will miraculously turn rng into a string.

Comment: No it does not... what is the input `rng` here? What do you think the output `rng` is? The question is about converting the contents of a range (over multiple cells) to a string variable, not formatting the contents of a single cell as a string...

Answer (score 0):

Any one of these functions will do it for you.

```
Function ConCatRange2(CellBlock As Range) As String
'for non-contiguous cells =ccr((a1:a10,c4,c6,e1:e5))
Dim Cell As Range
Dim sbuf As String
For Each Cell In CellBlock
If Len(Cell.Text) > 0 Then sbuf = sbuf & Cell.Text & ","
Next
ConCatRange2 = Left(sbuf, Len(sbuf) - 1)
End Function
```

OR

```
Function mergem(r As Range) As String
mergem = r.Cells(1, 1).Value
k = 1
For Each rr In r
    If k <> 1 Then
        mergem = mergem & "," & rr.Value
    End If
    k = 2
Next
End Function
```

OR

```
Function spliceUm(r As Range) As String
spliceUm = ""
For Each rr In r
spliceUm = spliceUm & rr.Value & ";"
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to convert a range to a string in VBA:

```
Sub convert()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Dim filter As String

filter = ""

Set rng = Selection

For Each cell In rng

    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        filter = """" & cell & """" & "," & filter
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: please explain on answers what you are doing and why this is a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Given the apparent need to iterate the range, I'd imagine it'd be considerably quicker to copy the range to an array first, and build the string by looping the array.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job, even with the Range in another Worksheet

```
Function RangeToString(ByVal myRange As range) As String
    RangeToString = ""
    If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
        RangeToString = "=" & myRange.Worksheet.Name & "!" & myRange.Address
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code, where I take into account for each rows to be enter as lines when application.transpose doesn't work for me.

```
Function RangeToString(ByVal myRange As Range) As String
RangeToString = ""
If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myRow As Range
    
    For Each myRow In myRange.Rows
        For Each myCell In myRow.Cells
        RangeToString = RangeToString & " " & myCell.Value
     Next myCell
        RangeToString = RangeToString & vbCr
    Next myRow
 
    'Remove extra space
    RangeToString = Right(RangeToString, Len(RangeToString) - 1)
End If 
End Function
```