# Can a Regex-Replace be run on a range instead of looping through the cells in Excel?

Tags: regex, vba, performance, excel

I need to do many Regex replacements (~ 100 currently, but the list will grow) on a range of cells (varies, but up to 4 or 5 digit cell count).
Currently, my working draft is to loop through all cells repeatedly for each pattern, but obviously  that's many loops.

Ideally, I'd call something like (pseudocode):

```
Sheet.Range("A1:G1000").RegexReplace(pattern, replacement)
```

However, the nearest thing is [`Range.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) which only mentions *"The string you want Microsoft Excel to search for"*.

The [list of `Regex.Replace` overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) does not mention anything related to cells or ranges.

So, since `Range.RegexReplace` seems to be out - **is there a more efficient way to replace many patterns in many cells than to loop through each pattern, row and column?**

Comment: Short answer, Nope. RegExp and Excel are two different worlds, the former was not designed for the latter, unfortunately.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Long answer - Convert range to string and replace there ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777996/how-can-i-convert-a-range-to-a-string-vba

Comment: I would personally dump both (range & your collections of regex patterns) to arrays and loop through them both. INF faster than going through the sheets. IF you work in arrays even though your iterating x by y itll be super fast

Comment: And exactly what do you think `Range("A1:G1000").RegexReplace` would be doing with every single cell in that range?

Comment: Sure it would have to run the regex on each cell, but I would assume the function to be better optimized than a simple loop through the cells (of course, @DougCoats has given a hint to improve this). The same thing applies to `Range.Replace`, which exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't iterate cells. Whether you're writing VBA, C#, or VB.NET, if you're working against `Range` objects in nested loops you're doing the single slowest thing you could possibly do with the Excel object model.

Work against an array instead - you **need** a function like this in your toolbox:

```
Public Function ToArray(ByVal target As Range) As Variant
    Select Case True
        Case target.Count = 1
            'singe cell
            ToArray = Array(target.Value)
        Case target.Rows.Count = 1
            'horizontal 1D range
            ToArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(target.Value))
        Case target.columns.Count = 1
            'vertical 1D range
            ToArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(target.Value)
        Case Else
            '2D array: let Excel to the conversion itself
            ToArray = target.Value
    End Select
End Function
```

Now you iterate an in-memory array of values (with `For` loops) and for each *value* you iterate a number of `Regex.Replace` calls - cache and reuse the `Regex` objects as much as possible, so you're not re-creating the same objects over and over and over for thousands of values.

Once you've traversed the entire array, dump it into the worksheet (resize and transpose as needed), and *voilà* - you've instantly rewritten thousands of cells in a single operation.

Comment: @MatsMug  isnt that just a prettier looking chunk of text? lol also obliguhtory typo just for you

Comment: Thank you! I didn't use your function, though. I used [RangeToStringArray by Simon Cowen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step) since I only do string operations.

Comment: @Pharaoh nested loops to convert the `Variant/String` to a `String` kinda defeat the purpose, but hey your call.

Comment: My assumption is that I have to do many loops (once for each pattern) to iterate the array anyways. If the string processing is faster with plain strings (assumption, too), I would bet my money on preprocessing the array and work with a string array. Please correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: You'll want an explicit `CStr` conversion at one point, indeed. But I'd rather have that conversion happen as late as possible, when I'm ready to regex-replace the would-be-String value, so that I only need to iterate the entire array *once*. Iterating the array *twice* to save on implicit Variant-to-String conversion doesn't seem right, especially since you're paying the conversion price *anyway*

Comment: Sounds reasonable, yes. Your remark *"iterate the entire array once"* gave me the idea to prepare all regex objects in an array first and iterate this array for each cell instead of iterating the whole cell array once per pattern.

Comment: That's the spirit!