# "The method got an invalid argument" error in Range("B1:B3").Value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fetch data from excel sheet into my SAP system with the help of following part of the code :

```
Dim xcl As Object

Dim wbk As Workbook

Dim sht As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set xcl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\....")

Set sht= wbk.Sheets("excel1")

Dim j As Integer

For j = 0 To 2

 **session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1," & Int(j) & "]").Text = sht.Range("B1:B3").Value**

Next j

End Sub
```

With lots of research on stackoverflow(@scriptman is my hero), i am finally able to fetch data in SAP system using " & Int(j) & ".
But it only works if  I am using sht.Range("B1").Value

If i use,  sht.Range("B1:B3").Value, I get error in the above bold line as 
"Runtime error 613"
The method got an invalid arguement"

Please help.
I am stuck at this since a month.

Comment: You're trying to pass an array to something that clearly expects a single value.

Comment: Fresh from today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802467/using-left-for-variable/44802555?

Comment: or try to replace the last part to `sht.Range("B1").Value`

Comment: `= sht.Range("B1:B3").Value` - Try entering `=B1:B3` in cell `D1`. What do you expect Excel to return for D1's value? You need to figure out which of the 3 values you want to assign to that text element; you can't assign a "bunch of values" to a single string.

Comment: @Mat'sMug : Then how can i pass a range of values?
I want values from B1 to B3 ..

Comment: You can't. You need to figure out a way to combine them into one single value. Concatenate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I pass a range of values?*

You don't. You can't put 3 cell values in 1 slot. You want `[B1:B3]` in 3 slots, so inside your 0-2 loop you'll take the cell in column `B` at row `j + 1` - I had a hard time formatting that ID string in the code block, so I extracted it into its own variable; it also makes the assignment instruction a bit clearer:

```
Dim id As String
id = "wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I"

For j = 0 To 2
    session.findById(id & "[1, " & j & "]").Text = sht.Range("B" & j + 1).Value
Next j
```

Comment: Absolutely correct!!
This works !!
Thankyou so much
Now i have 2 heroes : scriptman and mat's mug :)

Comment: Just one more thing..
It works with 3 fields
What if I have more than 10 fields in a column in excel sheet?
By your method, SAP is taking only 8 fields at one time.

Comment: You control the value of `j`. I don't know how the SAP API works, that's for you to figure out. Make it loop from 0 to 9 and you'll store `B1:B10` into `[1,0]` through `[1,9]`; whether or not that's valid depends on how the API works.

Comment: Actually what i am trying is after executing a transaction, I get bunch of user ids, then I copy it and paste it into another transaction window.
But the problem is "UPLOAD FROM CLIPBOARD" doesnot work in vba
hence, i copy the user ids into excel and then fetch them into SAP

Comment: @ScriptMan : can you help here?

Comment: And this is why asking about Y when you want to solve X, is wasting everyone's time. Good luck.

Comment: haha..that is because X does not work :)
So, we have to go through Y because Y will definitely work. Just need some help outta there :-)

Comment: What Mat'sMug is trying to tell you, @AnirudhChauhan, is that if you had "Actually" asked the "what I am trying to do..." part as your _original_ question, you'd have received an answer to that instead of finding a fix to a problem that doesn't actually address your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a sum, you can transfer it to SAP.

for example:

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP....ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1," & Int(j) & "]").Text = xcl.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("B1:B3"))

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: yayy!!
Scriptman to the rescue :)
Now the error doesnot show up, but it shows 0 in all the three boxes in SAP
why is that so?

Comment: First I would test the formula without SAP only in Excel. for example: sht.Range("A1").value = xcl.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("B1:B3"))

Comment: i checked !!
Still returning value as 0.

Comment: Then the error is in the formula or in the cells to which the formula refers. But you can also test the following. for example: = sht.Range("B1").Value + sht.Range("B2").Value + sht.Range("B3").Value

Comment: Still it is returning as 0.
Just a small doubt, why are you using Sum function ?
We dont want to add the values
We just want a set of values in the column(User ids) to be copied into SAP field columns

Comment: Cant we do something like this?
rng=Range("B1:B3")
sht.Range("rng").Value

Not sure.
need help with the syntax

Comment: It does not help. You would have to present the contents of the 3 affected cells here. Then one could talk about it further.

Comment: The cells contain User IDs like BC1234, CD1234, BCDEFG

Comment: @AnirudhChauhan you have 3 values and 1 slot. Either you add them up to make 1 value, or you find 2 more slots so you can fit your 3 values.

Comment: Now we know, the values can not be added. Do you want to pass the value from Excel, depending on "j"? This could be realized as follows: session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP....ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1," & Int(j) & "]").Text = sht.Range("B" & cstr(j+1))

Comment: @Mat'sMug : I dont have one slot
i have multiple slots in SAP fields. It is like a column
Hence, I am using j variable in for loop to fetch the values

Comment: @ScriptMan : No...it does not depend on j.
j variable is used in for loop as column number in SAP field.

Likewise, we can use variable i to loop the column number in excel
Do you know any sort of this possibility?

Comment: To understand what you want to do, you should assign the values from Excel in the following way. for example: session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP....ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = "BC1234"; session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP....ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").Text = "CD1234"; session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP....ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,2]").Text = "BCDEFG"

Comment: @ScriptMan : I cannot do that..because I dont know what will be the value of these fields
Moreover, It is not just these three. There are upto 80 userids

Comment: Too bad it did not work. In the 6th comment before, the solution you did accept later was already available.

Comment: @ScriptMan : no worries, scriptman
you will always be my hero :)